# addToFolder(): The copy version of the file is deleted, if the original version is deleted

Tags: copy, google-apps-script, directory, google-sheets

I started doing development with google scripts few days ago and recently joined stackoverflow. I have a problem with addToFolder() function. I have the following piece of code that copies my new spreadsheet into a folder (test/sheets) in my Google Drive:

```js
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.create("test");
var ssID = ss.getId();
DocsList.getFileById(ssID).addToFolder(DocsList.getFolder("test/sheets"));
```

My problem is that now I have 2 versions of the same file (one in the root of my Google Drive folder and the other in test/sheets folder), whenever I try to delete either of the copies, the other copy is deleted as well. Is there a way to delete the old file and keep the new one OR is there a way to create the file in the desired folder in first place?

---

**EDIT :**

thanks for you quick response. I played with this for couple of hours but still have problem copying the file to the destination folder. The problem is that even when I use makeCopy Method of the file, still addToFolder is the only option to mention the folder. Again this ends up having the tagged filename in the destination folder. 
I had the same problem with the copy method.
Here is my new Code:

```
var SetLocationFile = "icompare/sheets/stocks" 
var FolderID = DocsList.getFolder(SetLocationFile); 
var FileID = DocsList.getFileById(ssID); 
FileID.makeCopy("test3").addToFolder(FolderID);
```

Comment: I'd like to ask just one question to be sure I understand your point : how do you look at the content of your folder ? Do you use the drive browser interface or the system finder (or explorer) ? If in the browser, what "view" do you use ?  Well I know that's 3 questions ;-) forgive me

Comment: I view the content of my folders in Google Drive browser using List view. My internet browser is google Chrome!

Answer (score 5):

Folders in Google Docs\Google Drive are actually tags. When you "add" a file to the folder "test/sheets", you do not make a copy of your file, you just attach the tag "test/sheets" to it. Now the same file is shown both in the "test/sheets" folder (i.e. in the list of all files with the tag "test/sheets") and in the root. If you wish to make a copy of the file, you should use the [copy](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_docslist#copy) method. (Please let me know if I just misunderstand your question.)

Comment: ah ha!  the light dawns. Then why the hell do they call them "folders" ? anyway, thanks for the help. I was thinking of the folders as containers and it didn't make ANY sense.

Answer (score 2):

I realize this is an old questions but you can simply use `.removeFromFolder(DocsList.getRootFolder());` to remove the file from the root folder.

Answer (score 0):

I would also like to know the answer to this question.. seems rather "weird" that the API does not even provide a way to create spreadsheets and place them in a certain map? And no, I do not want a Copy of the file, I want the file to be in a specific map and in no other map...

Comment: See this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11910734/google-apps-script-how-do-i-create-a-file-in-a-folder