# How to move generated PDF to a specific folder in Google Drive

Tags: pdf

Here is the jist of what I want this script to do.

User submits a form using Google Forms
Form Records to Google Sheet
Sheet replaces text and generate Google Document from Template
Template is copied
PDF is created from this template
PDF is emailed
PDF is moved to a specific folder in Google Drive.

I have all of those things to work except the last step. Can someone help us out here? We are using this for a school, and nobody in our (IT) department knows anything about scripts. Through Googling and searching I have come this far. The last step is to get the PDF to move to a specific folder.

Here is the current code:

```
// MacArthur High School
// Generic PLC Agenda Script
// Created 18 Jul 2014
// Author: Josh Patrick
// Decatur Public Schools #61

// Document Creation - replace docTemplate links with each template link on the PLC Drive. 

var docTemplate = "1DSFCE6mFZib0ZTVOgVqPbLYaRwjS-XNsnsZn5RZewsE"; 
var docName = "PLC Agenda";

// Form Functions (labeled identifiers for Form)

function onFormSubmit(e) {
  var TimeStamp = e.values [0]
  var MeetingDate = e.values [1];
  var MeetingTime = e.values [2];
  var MeetingLocation = e.values [3];
  var PLCFocus = e.values [4];
  var PlannedActions = e.values [5];
  var ResourcesNeeded = e.values [6];
  var AssignedEmail = "jwpatrick@dps61.org";

// Get document template, copy it as a new temp doc, and save the Doc’s id
var copyId = DocsList.getFileById(docTemplate)
.makeCopy(docName+' for '+ MeetingDate)
.getId();


// Open the temporary document
var copyDoc = DocumentApp.openById(copyId);

// Get the document’s body section
var copyBody = copyDoc.getActiveSection();

// Replacing Text with Form Information

copyBody.replaceText('keyMeetingDate', MeetingDate);
copyBody.replaceText('keyMeetingTime', MeetingTime);
copyBody.replaceText('keyMeetingLocation', MeetingLocation);
copyBody.replaceText('keyPLCFocus' , PLCFocus);
copyBody.replaceText('keyPlannedActions' , PlannedActions);
copyBody.replaceText('keyResourcesNeeded' ResourcesNeeded);


// Copy Document and Save

copyDoc.saveAndClose();

// Generate PDF  
var pdf = DocsList.getFileById(copyId).getAs("application/pdf");

// Email
var subject = "ELA PLC Agenda for " + MeetingDate ;
var body = "Attached is the PDF copy of the ELA PLC Agenda for " + MeetingDate;
MailApp.sendEmail(AssignedEmail, subject, body, {htmlBody: body, attachments: pdf});

// Delete Temporary Document
DocsList.getFileById(copyId).setTrashed(true);
}
```

**** Instead of deleting the temporary document, I want to move it to a specific file in Google Drive. I have looked up the scripts help, but I don't think I have done it correctly. I can get it to copydoc but I cannot get it to move to the right folder.

Any assistance is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`addToFolder` may fit your need.

[developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/docs-list/file#addToFolder(Folder)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/docs-list/file#addToFolder(Folder))

Comment: I'm confused at how that would function. I just need to know how I can move the temporary PDF file that gets deleted to a folder. I am not sure how that would work. (maybe I'm looking at it the wrong way or missing a step)

Comment: @user3853429 I found an very intuitive use of addToFolder here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11494223/addtofolder-the-copy-version-of-the-file-is-deleted-if-the-original-version